# The service role arn:aws:iam::20011470201:role/deploy doesn't have permission to perform the following operation: autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, bitbucket, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

Has anyone come across the below error before?

> The service role arn:aws:iam::20011470201:role/deploy doesn't have permission to perform the following operation: autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks

I have code-deploy set-up between by bit-bucket account and my Amazon AWS instance. 
I am able to deploy to the test server everyday without issue.
But when i try to add the instance of our production server to the list of instances, i get the above error

**Note:**  I have added this instance and successfully deployed the code in the past , i'm not sure why i get this error now.

Any directions/hints on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how i missed it, but the policy i had defined was missing the ***"autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks"***, once i added this to the existing permission everything worked fine.

Then again, the policy has not changed in well over a year, not sure why aws did not complain about this earlier

Answer (score 0):

We currently rolled out a fix for permission issues between CodeDeploy and AutoScaling. Previously CodeDeploy doesn't require autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks to describe or create a lifecycle hook to AutoScaling, when customer's deplyoment group contains AutoScaling groups. But now we started to require this permission, which is actually the right way and also expected. Adding the proper permission fixes the problem.

Thanks,
Binbin

Answer (score 0):

I see that you fixed this. Can you paste an example config here so noobs like me know just how to place this bit of code? Oh, and I can't comment on your accepted solution yet, not enough points...